# Why can't I assign a property to self in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, decorator

I want to create an attribute in class that connected to another attribute. for example `biz` is `bar+1`.

The next code is working:

```py
class Foo:

     def __init__(self, bar, biz=None):

         self.bar = bar

     biz = property(lambda self: self.bar + 1)

print(Foo(0).biz+1)
```

and print `2`. But when I move the `biz` declaretion into the initializer, for example to apply a condition, I get an error:

```py
class Foo:

     def __init__(self, bar, biz=None):

         self.bar = bar

         if biz is None:

            self.biz = property(lambda self: self.bar + 1)

         else:

            self.biz = biz

print(Foo(0).biz+1)
```

return `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'property' and 'int'`

Why python relate to the attribute as 'property' type and not as 'int'?

EDIT:
I found that if I use `self.__class__.biz=property(...)` it's working, but I'm still asking why I can't use property locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties are implemented using [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#closing-thoughts). As per the docs:

> A descriptor is what we call any object that defines `__get__()`,
> `__set__()`, or `__delete__()`.
>
> Optionally, descriptors can have a `__set_name__()` method. This is only
> used in cases where a descriptor needs to know either the class where
> it was created or the name of class variable it was assigned to. (This
> method, if present, is called even if the class is not a descriptor.)
>
> Descriptors get invoked by the dot operator during attribute lookup.
> If a descriptor is accessed indirectly with
> `vars(some_class)[descriptor_name]`, the descriptor instance is returned
> without invoking it.
>
> **Descriptors only work when used as class variables. When put in
> instances, they have no effect.**
>
> The main motivation for descriptors is to provide a hook allowing
> objects stored in class variables to control what happens during
> attribute lookup.
>
> Traditionally, the calling class controls what happens during lookup.
> Descriptors invert that relationship and allow the data being
> looked-up to have a say in the matter.
>
> Descriptors are used throughout the language. It is how functions turn
> into bound methods. Common tools like `classmethod()`, `staticmethod()`,
> `property()`, and `functools.cached_property()` are all implemented as
> descriptors.

In the first case, you set the property on the class level, which is why it works. This is also why it works when you do `self.__class__.biz=property(...)`. However, you should not modify the class definition from an instance constructor, as creating multiple instances will overwrite the property being set on the class.

To achieve your goal, I would instead write the property like this:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar, biz=None):
        self.bar = bar
        self._biz = biz

    @property
    def biz(self):
        if self._biz is None:
            return self.bar + 1
        else:
            return self._biz
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "python magic". In general, you can expect for [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) and such to have special behaviors that things you made would not have. `property` is one of these.

You can find much more detail in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) but the TL;DR is that `__get__` is a special function which tells python that you have a property and "get" requests should be done in a property-like fashion.

To illustrate what's going on, let's dive a bit deeper.

```py
# A custom from-scratch property-like class.
class MyBareProperty(object):
    def __init__(self, _bp_name, getter):
        self.getter = getter
        self._bp_name = _bp_name
        print('bare property init', self._bp_name, getter)
    
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        print('bare property __get__', self._bp_name, obj, objtype)
        return self.getter(obj)

# A sub-class of the built-in property.
class MyProperty(property):
    def __init__(self, _mp_name, *args, **kwargs):
        self._mp_name = _mp_name
        print('property init', self._mp_name, args, kwargs)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def __get__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('property __get__', self._mp_name, args, kwargs)
        return super().__get__(*args, **kwargs)

# Our thin test class
class Something(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        # Does not work. Functions are class data, not instance data.
        # Python does not do property-like behavior for instance data.
        self.b = MyProperty('b', lambda s: s.a+1)
        # Attaching the property to the class works
        type(self).d = MyProperty('d', lambda s: s.a+3)
        Something.e = MyProperty('e', lambda s: s.a+4)
        # Our bare property does not work
        self.f = MyBareProperty('f', lambda s: s.a+5)
    
    # Vars defined here are class data.
    c = MyProperty('c', lambda s: s.a+2)
    g = MyBareProperty('g', lambda s: s.a+6)


def main():
    something = Something(1)
    # Get a works as expected
    print('a', type(something.a), something.a)
    # Get b returns the property instance itself, not the calculated value
    print('b', type(something.b), something.b)
    Something.b2 = something.b
    # The same property instance as a class var now works.
    # This behavior is hard-coded into python.
    print('b2 = instance b', type(something.b2), something.b2)
    # Class data property works
    print('c', type(something.c), something.c)
    # Attaching to type(self) in __init__ also works
    print('d', type(something.d), something.d)
    # Explicitly attaching to named class in __init__ works
    print('e', type(something.e), something.e)
    # Our custom property does not work as instance var
    print('f', type(something.f), something.f)
    # Our custom property does work as class data
    print('g', type(something.g), something.g)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
property init c (<function Something.<lambda> at 0x000002466FB111B0>,) {}
bare property init g <function Something.<lambda> at 0x000002466FB11240>
property init b (<function Something.__init__.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002466FB112D0>,) {}
property init d (<function Something.__init__.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002466FB11360>,) {}
property init e (<function Something.__init__.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002466FB113F0>,) {}
bare property init f <function Something.__init__.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002466FB11480>
a <class 'int'> 1
b <class '__main__.MyProperty'> <__main__.MyProperty object at 0x000002466F58D2A0>
property __get__ b (<__main__.Something object at 0x000002466FB17D00>, <class '__main__.Something'>) {}
property __get__ b (<__main__.Something object at 0x000002466FB17D00>, <class '__main__.Something'>) {}
b2 = instance b <class 'int'> 2
property __get__ c (<__main__.Something object at 0x000002466FB17D00>, <class '__main__.Something'>) {}
property __get__ c (<__main__.Something object at 0x000002466FB17D00>, <class '__main__.Something'>) {}
c <class 'int'> 3
property __get__ d (<__main__.Something object at 0x000002466FB17D00>, <class '__main__.Something'>) {}
property __get__ d (<__main__.Something object at 0x000002466FB17D00>, <class '__main__.Something'>) {}
d <class 'int'> 4
property __get__ e (<__main__.Something object at 0x000002466FB17D00>, <class '__main__.Something'>) {}
property __get__ e (<__main__.Something object at 0x000002466FB17D00>, <class '__main__.Something'>) {}
e <class 'int'> 5
f <class '__main__.MyBareProperty'> <__main__.MyBareProperty object at 0x000002466FB17C10>
bare property __get__ g <__main__.Something object at 0x000002466FB17D00> <class '__main__.Something'>
bare property __get__ g <__main__.Something object at 0x000002466FB17D00> <class '__main__.Something'>
g <class 'int'> 7
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, the property isn't working as expected because the expected behavior occurs only when a property object is a class attribute, not an instance attribute, due to the [Descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-descriptor) Protocol. However, what exactly is happening when your version of the code is ran, and why exactly is Python returning `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'property' and 'int'`?

Here is the chain of relevant events:

- The line `self.biz = property(lambda self: self.bar + 1)` sets the value of `self.biz` to be a property object.
- On the line `print(Foo(0).biz+1)` - `print` is given an expression in the form of `x + y` that tries to add two elements using the `+` operand.
- The `y` of the `x + y` is `1`, which is an `int`.
- The `x` of the `x + y` is the expression `Foo(0).biz`. `Foo(0)` instantiates a an object of type `Foo` which has two attributes: `bar` with the value of `0` (an `int`), and `biz` with the value of an object of type `property` that was created during instantiation of the `Foo` object. However, as others have explained, when a `property` object is a class attribute and is accessed from an instance, the Descriptor Protocol is activated and returns the return value of one of `__get__`, `__set__`, or `__delete__` methods of the `property` object, depending on how the attribute was accessed. However, since you have assigned the `property` object to the instance itself, the Descriptor Protocol will not work. This doesn't mean that the `property` object itself isn't working: it's still successfully created and is there, but when accessed as an instance attribute (as with `Foo(0).biz`) - the accessing simply returns the property object itself. Therefore, the value of `x` in the `x + y` expression is the `property` object itself, rather than the value of the object's `__get__` method that you were expecting.
- Therefore, the arguments to the `print` function are a `property object` + `int object`. Since the `property` object hasn't implemented an `__add__` method, Python returns `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'property' and 'int'`.

To prove this, remove the `+1` at the end off the print statement, and imply simply run `print(Foo(0).biz)` to see what it evaluates to. Something like `<property object at 0x000001CECE7401D0>` gets printed to the screen, showing that the rest of the code works, and that `Foo(0).biz` does indeed evaluate to a `property` object.

Answer (score -1):

Absolutely, when I call type on the self.biz I get `<class 'property'>`.

You can also do

```py
class Foo:

     def __init__(self, bar, biz=None):

         self.bar = bar

         if biz is None:

            self.biz = self.bar + 1

         else:

            self.biz = biz
```

Comment: I want it as property because `bar` can be changed later.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).